# Symfony 4.4 not iclude .env.local

Tags: symfony, symfony-4.4

4 (upgraded) . And .env.local is not included what can be a reason ?

```
requirements 

 "symfony/acl-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/asset": "^4.4",
        "symfony/console": "^4.4",
        "symfony/expression-language": "^4.4",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
        "symfony/form": "^4.4",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.4",
        "symfony/http-client": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/mercure-bundle": "^0.2.3",
        "symfony/messenger": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/mime": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.3",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/process": "^4.4",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "^4.4",
        "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.2",
        "symfony/translation": "^4.4",
        "symfony/validator": "^4.4",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "^4.4",
        "symfony/web-link": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.6",
        "symfony/yaml": "^4.4",


 "require-dev": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "^4.4",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.7",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/test-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "^4.4"
    },
```

.env is parsed correctly

i have "symfony/dotenv": "^4.4",
but test "symfony/dotenv": "v5.2.4",  - same sitation

Comment: "[Open the .env file (or better, the .env.local file if you CREATED one)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#selecting-the-active-environment)"

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found - public/index.php was not updated from 4.4 after copy from 4.4 .env.local is included